# how to upgrade simple_form gem for bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I updated my application by moving to bootstrap 3 from version 2 by replacing the css files etc.

I thought I'd upgrade `simple_from` as well since the old one is probably incompatible with bootstrap 2.

So I ran `bundle update simple_form` and it upgraded from simple_form (2.0.4) to  (2.1.1).

How do I upgrade to the lastest version? and how do I integrate it with bootstrap 3? Do I need to reinstall simple_form using `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap` instead of updating the gem with bundler ? and how come updating the gem didn't update to the latest one?

Thank you for the clarifications on how to migrate simple_form properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 support for simple_form has not made it into a stable release yet. You can read more [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/04/bootstrap-3-support-for-simple-form/). If you want to install the rc version, which seems to work fine, simply use `gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'` in the Gemfile. (Run `bundle install` after making the change)

I'm not sure how simple_form generators work, but one way of making sure the configuration is updated is by copying config files from the [sample application](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap). The files are `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` and `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb`.

If there are other simple_form-related files leftover from the previous version, you should probably delete them.

Comment: OP shows rails v3.2, which simple_form no longer supports in their 3.x releases.  We are stuck upgrading to Rails4 to have simple_form (in rc1 and rc2) with bootstrap3 (and ditching the other gems that have not made it to rails4, and adding the gems that undo rails4 'features').